# Animation transition for modal

Tags: html, css

This is my html modal code

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-background"></div>
```

This is my CSS

```
  modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 53px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: opacity 0.4s, bottom 0.4s; 
    opacity: 1;      

    .modal-body {
      padding-left: 70px;
      background: #fff;
      border: 0;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    }
  }

  .modal-background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 55px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.75;
    z-index: 900;
  }
}

body.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have tried to add slide down animation transition when open modal, but i dont know why this didn't work, can someone help me?. Thanks in advance

Comment: You're never changing the `bottom` value of the modal, is there some code missing? Transition won't do anything if the property it's transitioning doesn't change

Comment: i created this modal based on this tutorial https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-modal-windows. there is any way to add slide down animation transition? @Rylee